# Is it possible to call methods from one controller on another in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

If I am in a `"signin"` controller can I execute the method `get_user_info()` which resides in the `"user"` controller? If so, what would be the syntax for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not saying this *can't* be done, however it really *shouldn't* be done.

Something like this is exactly what a [library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html) is meant for.

Create a library which handles functions such as `get_user_info()` and then load and call that library within whichever controllers need access to it.

You can still have a controller named `user` and a library named `user` as well (though that could get confusing).

Check out CI's guide for info on [how to create a library](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

****Edit****

As people have mentioned models could also serve the purpose of making functions usable in multiple places.

Personally I like to keep only business logic within models (the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations) and any logical operations which must be done in multiple places I create a library for.

Comment: +1, though instead of a library, I'd use a model for this.  This is more like what models are for.

Comment: @Rocket that could depend on what exactly `get_user_info` does, but most likely a `library` and a `model` would both be needed for user operations.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at HMVC? 
 https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

it will look something like modules::run('module/controller/method', $params, $...);